# Maven will not pull in boolean from visible project

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio

I am currently working on adding the ability for a server admin to enable or disable screen capturing on a server from the backend. I have two projects, Ion and security. Security can see ion but ion cannot see security. I have a boolean called secureWindowCapability. I cannot figure out what is not allowing me to include a few of these statements down below.

This statement declares the secureWindowCapability in the ion project

```
public static boolean secureWindowCapability = false;
```

The security project cannot seem to see the declaration.

```
IonActivity.(Cannot see the secureWindowCapability);
```

The IonActivity class can see other get methods in the project fine, but cannot see my temp method to test out the issue. I have also made sure to save and use ./gradlew install. I have re-cloned the project and I am still running into the issue. I have mavenLocal in the gradle, and have asked my superiors and we cannot seem to figure out the issue. I am resorting to ask on here. I am more of a beginner coder, and I am not the best at explaining the issue, if you have any questions or need more info to get a fix please post it in the questions.

Comment: Can you see any autocomplete suggestion at all? Sometimes, it may be slow to display the suggestions

Comment: Can you please change the title with a summary of your problem? With this title, people cannot know if they can answer your question or not without reading all of the text.

Comment: @mettleap When typing in IonActivity. it will auto complete with other methods. I created a few methods that were exactly like that method but did not work. I have also finished this project before, but there was an issue and the code was deleted when creating a code review. So I know it worked previously but does not work now

Comment: @D.Foskett, ok, I do not use maven or android studio much, but might it be that you have not built the Ion project and/or the security project? Maybe you could try that ...

Comment: I have built them several times, this is a weird issue I have never ran in to. I will go ahead and try again, but it has not worked in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version name of the ion project had to be changed to 6.8.5 instead of 6.8.0. The security project was pulling from the wrong cache, and would not let go of the old cache even after deleting the cache. Changing the version to a newer one cleared up the issue.